# Entity Framework resetting int values to 0 on inherited object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been about 4 hours trying to find out what I'm doing wrong with this TPT hierarchy, it's been a big pain in the neck.

I have base class:

```
public partial class Registry
{
     public int Id_Audit{get;set;}
     public string CUD{get;set;} //Key Value
     public bool Canceled{get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Articles> Articles {get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Paid> Paids {get;set;}
     //Other base properties
}

public partial class Sale : Registry
{
     public int idsale{get;set;}
}

public partial class Cuote : Registry
{
     public int idCuote{get;set;}
     public int Consec{get;set;}
     public int Modification{get;set;}
     //Other Cuote properties
}
```

At runtime interacts with a `Registry` object until it's decided which object will going to be: `Sale` or `Cuote`, so I made an extension class to export base class to a derived class

```
public partial class Registry
{
     public Sales ToSale()
     {
        Sale r = new Sale
        {
            Canceled = this.Canceled,
            CUD = this.CUD,
            Id_Auditoria = this.Id_Auditoria,
            //other properties
        };
        return r;
     }
}
```

The same function was made for cuotes.

So I use it like this

```
Sale s = tempRegistry.ToSale();
dbContext.Registrys.Add(s);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But every time, `SaveChanges()` throws an exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Registrys_Audits". The conflict occurred in database "testDB", table "dbo.Audits", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

But the property is set before `SaveChanges()` executes, but after `SaveChanges()` is not.

Here's a caption (Names are a little bit different, Id_Auditoria == `Id_Audit`, Registros_Auditoria == `Registry` ):

[image: Before]

On Catch

[image: After]

My database schema is this:
[image: Schema]
As you can see there is no more manipulation for the `Sale` object
So why it's keeping throwing me that exception?

Comment: may be the id is null. null is automatically converted to zero in c# if property is not defined to allow null value.

Comment: Where does `tempRegistry` come from? Is it attached to the context and does it have an associated `Auditoria` object?

Comment: @GertArnold `tempRegistry` is a instance of `Registry` class on my main form, this object is binded to the controls, then the user decides what type of registry will going to be, the specific properties are set and then is added to the context

Comment: @JSantosh the Id_Auditoria is setted before SaveChanges() but after is not, it's not clear to me, which id are you talking about?

Comment: i was speaking about attribute `id` whose value is  zero in screenshot.

Comment: two tables `registrys` and `audits` have a foreign key. the `id` that you are using to insert data into `audits` has value zero , but there is no record in `registrys` with `id=0` (id in audits is mapped to one of the column in registrys), better post the FK relation of these 2 tables

Comment: @JSantosh I see, I added the database schema, an `Audit` contains multiple registrys that could be `Sale` or `Cuote`, I translate almost all the code and the schema, so if there some irregularity please tell me to clarify.

Comment: I suggest you post more code...Registros_Auditora is of what type? Please make what you are trying to do clear. PS i know you have made effort to this end! but...a little more of the actual code... Cozs i cant not work out what is what type with your sample. Also I assume this is an existing Db.. based on all the weird db naming and conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Hi everyone finally it work, I'm not quite sure what was the exact problem, I was forced to rebuilt the entity framework model, rename classes etc. and one of the most important change was

- Deleted relationships between inherited objects: The default navigation properties were not deleted in the previous model, so apparently EntityFramework was trying to read `Sale`.`Registry` instead of the base class.

Thank you for all your help.